# Not working keyboard while installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, keyboard, 22.04, usb-installation

the first time i installed ubuntu the keyboard was working but at the end it gave me an error.  after that when i try to install ubuntu again the keyboard doesn't work. But it works bios.only mouse works

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Unfortunately there is not enough information here to offer any solutions. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) a clearly-stated version of Ubuntu (1) the brand/model/specs of your computer. With this, it may be possible to recognize the issue and answer the question 